# Kerberos - доверенные домены

Tags: linux, ubuntu, active-directory, kerberos

Есть домены на Windows Server (Active Directory), связанные между собой доверительными отношениями. Есть машина с Ubuntu 20.04, на которой надо авторизовать пользователей из ВСЕХ доверенных доменов. Эта машина видит только контроллер одного домена (пусть это будет DomainA), другие контроллеры для неё недоступны, но при этом контроллер DomainA видит контроллеры всех доверенных доменов. (Не спрашивайте почему. Так устроена сеть и переделывать её никто не будет.) Как при данных условиях настроить kerberos на Ubuntu таким образом, чтобы можно было авторизовать пользователей по имени и паролю на доверенных доменах (DomainB, DomainC и т.д.)?

P.S. Если это невозможно сделать при помощи Kerberos, можно рассмотреть другие варианты авторизации.

Comment: А чё, по `login@domainB` не едет?

Comment: Не едет. ```kinit user-b@domain-b.local\n kinit: Cannot contact any KDC for realm 'domain-b.local' while getting initial credentials```

Comment: Так, а тачка на винде 7/10 в доменеА может тусануть в Б и С?

Comment: Вы бы конфиг krb5.conf светанули хоть.